# can't open twitter url in android webview

Tags: android, url, twitter, webview, loading

I have a problem in my ANDROID application.

I would like to display a twitter page in my webview but the URL won't open.

It keeps loading infinitely.

I am using sdk 1.6.

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    final Activity activity = this;
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
            Log.e("progress",progress+" "+((progress * 100)));
            if(progress==100)
            {
                //getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_OFF);
                indicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                indicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new ApplicationWebViewClient());
}

    private class ApplicationWebViewClient extends WebViewClient { 
    @Override 
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the url is correct?

Comment: yes...the url is correct and a have the mobile twitter page which loades infintiely on android webview...but when i use the browser it works perfectly !

Answer (score 13):

```
wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

This worked for me!

Comment: Added this but not working am using the webview client.

Answer (score 9):

I had to set the User Agent String on the webview to get it to work.

wv.getSettings().setUserAgentString("silly_that_i_have_to_do_this");

and that worked for me.

Hope it helps someone else!

Comment: weird... just noticed in one of my website logs that a user agent of a visitor was "silly_that_i_have_to_do_this".....

Comment: I think that the application "QR Reader for Android" uses this user-agent across the board:

[see a comment at:
http://www.androlib.com/android.application-comment.uk-tapmedia-qrreader-wDzFt.aspx?p=5 ]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` needs to return true to indicate that the host application is managing the load:

```
private class ApplicationWebViewClient extends WebViewClient { 
    @Override 
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have made this change but same issue...the loading wheel of mobile twitter page is stoping for a while but continues to animate after...but in the browser when the twitter loading wheel is stopped for a while the page is redirected to the specific url after

Comment: You are calling `webview.loadUrl()` somewhere, aren't you? And you have set `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in your Manifest?